# how to create a partition in free space using GNU Parted

Tags: parted

Below is my hard disk shown in gnu parted:

```
(parted) print free                                                       
Model: ATA HGST HTS541075A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                     
       17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot
2      538MB   468GB   467GB   ext4
       468GB   520GB   52.4GB  Free Space
6      520GB   527GB   6353MB  linux-swap(v1)
4      527GB   527GB   524MB   ext4
5      527GB   744GB   217GB                                         lvm
3      744GB   750GB   6352MB
    750GB   750GB   892kB   Free Space

(parted)
```

You can see I have 52.4GB space (fourth entry). I want to create a partition in this. I know `mkpart` is the command for it.

Its syntax is

```
 mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END
```

But my problem is I don't know what value is should give for `START` and `END`. What value should I use?

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but `cfdisk` allows to do that extremely easy: you just press on the Free space, and it asks you about the needed partition size (100% by default, so you don't have to calculate anything).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system
    ......................................
        468GB   520GB   52.4GB  Free Space
```

Well, as you can see *Start* is `468GB` and *End* is `520GB`. Now, `parted` defaults to `MB` so you'll have to specify the `unit`:

```
unit GB mkpart primary ntfs 468 520
```

or append *unit* suffix to the start/end numbers:

```
mkpart primary ext2 468GB 520GB
```

Alternatively, you can list the values in `MB` with

```
unit MB print free
```

and then use the start/end values without any unit/suffix e.g.

```
mkpart primary ext2 468012 520008
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this five times. Clean, simple, useful. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Another solution would be to use percentage unit (%) to specify sizes:

```
 sudo parted -s /dev/sdX mkpart primary 0% 100%
```

If a label is not present in the disk device, you will need to create it first. For example:

```
 sudo parted -s /dev/sdX mklabel msdos
```

**Caution!** 0% and 100% points correspondingly to the start and to the end of entire physical disk, and not just free space. So if you run `sudo parted -s /dev/sdX mkpart primary 0% 100%`, this will destroy all existing partitions.

Comment: How can it make sense to specify 0% and 100%?

Comment: well, it is a simple (but quite common) use case where you want to span over all available space (from 0% to 100%) to create a partition

Comment: You mean, create one partition that spans the entire physical disk?  (Destroying the six other partitions that already exist?)

Comment: Yes, that would destroy all other partitions. My post only answers a simple case of the question (of the title), not the specific case presented at the 1st post.

Comment: No, the question title asks ''how to create a partition *in free space*'' (emphasis added).  If your command destroys existing partitions, then it's not using just the disk's free space.

Comment: Downvoted because this a dangerous command that destroys existing partitions.

Comment: Also downvoted for it's dangerous and comes with no warning or proper explanation. The use of percentage is a nice advice but the offered command -- to this question -- should be preceded by proper text/warning.